# Switch another player (after END the game, it should be switch another player)

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a simple dice game for windows forms application using c#.

Now, I got problem with switching the player either 1 or 2.

First, when i clicked the start button, it will show the number of the player which is 1 or 2 and then the textboxes will be disabled.
--> this portion no problem... can play with the player 1 or 2

But, when i want to END the game which is from player 1 to become player 2.
it should be changed the number and disabled the player 1 for the textboxes.

the problem is when i clicked on the END button, it shows the player number changed become 0.

```
    private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random RndRandom;
        RndRandom = new Random();

        int player = RndRandom.Next(1, 3);
        tbxOutputPlayer.Text = player.ToString();

        if (player == 1)
        {
            tbxPlayer2.Enabled = false;
            tbxPlayer1.Enabled = true;
            //tbxOutputPlayer.Text = "Player 1 start the game";
        }

        else if (player == 2)
        {
            tbxPlayer1.Enabled = false;
            tbxPlayer2.Enabled = true;
            //tbxOutputPlayer.Text = "Player 2 start the game";
        }
    }

    private void btnEnd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (player == 1)
        {
            player = 2;
            tbxOutputPlayer.Text = player.ToString();
        }else if (player == 2)
        {
            player = 1;
            tbxOutputPlayer.Text = player.ToString();
        }
        //if(player == 1)
        //{
        //    tbxOutputPlayer.Text = "player 1 ends the game";
        //    tbxPlayer2.Enabled = true;
        //    tbxPlayer1.Enabled = false;
        //}
        //else if (player == 2)
        //{
        //    tbxOutputPlayer.Text = "player 2 ends the game";
        //    tbxPlayer1.Enabled = true;
        //    tbxPlayer2.Enabled = false;
        //}
    }
```

Comment: i mean like if i clicked the end button, the number is become 0 and it would not changed the player. right now, i solved the problem already because i declared the player two times. one inside of the play button button and the other one is outside.

Comment: Do you set `player` (to zero) elsewhere in your program?

Comment: You probably have two definitions of player. One in your class, which you don't touch or set to 0 and the one you define locally in btnPlay_Click

Comment: Please check what you are getting in variable Player when you click end.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code and i hope it will work.

```
private void btnEnd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToString(tbxOutputPlayer.Text)== "1")
        {
            tbxOutputPlayer.Text = "2";
        }else if (Convert.ToString(tbxOutputPlayer.Text)== "2")
        {
            tbxOutputPlayer.Text = "1";
        }

    }
```